# linux mmu: vma->vm_start vs mm->vm_start

Tags: linux-kernel, mmu

I can't understand the relations of mm_struct.start_data and vm_area_struct.vm_start

```
vma = find_vma(mm, mm->start_data);
DBG("mm->start_data(%p) vma->vm_start(%p) mm->end_data(%p) vma->vm_end(%p)\n", (uvp_t)mm->start_data, (uvp_t)vma->vm_start, (uvp_t)mm->end_data, (uvp_t)vma->vm_end);
ASSERT(mm->start_data >= vma->vm_start);
```

I find corresponding vm_area_struct for address represented by mm->start_data and I can't understand why the data is not aligned by vm_start and vm_end boundaries. I have the following:
|vma->vm_start|----------|mm->start_data|---------|vma->vm_end|------|mm->end_data|

```
 mm->start_data(08049f00) vma->vm_start(08049000) mm->end_data(0804a07a) vma->vm_end(0804a000)
```

Answer (score 1):

vma->vm_start(08049000), vma->vm_end(0804a000) - Indicates the used memory page.
mm->start_data(08049f00), mm->end_data(0804a07a) - Indicates the actual location of the data.
Read more: [Linux Device Drivers, Third Edition - Chapter 15: Memory Mapping and DMA](http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/).